# Postfix error log has "DKIM verify result: Message is not signed"

Tags: postfix, dkim

What may be causing this issue?

How can I diagnose it?

I've just enabled SMTP via an additional entry in `master.cf`.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it is a missing DKIM signature or an service option which checks for DKIM signed messages. You should consult your logs or enable [more verbose debugging options](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html).

We do not really know in which context this error occurs and if *postfix* throws this error. It might be another service like **OpenDKIM** which gives a result back to postfix - then you should debug the execution and communication with this service.

*Without logs and configuration files, it is hard to give a correct answer.*